# Soundflower input applications

Tags: c++, cocoa, audio, core-audio

I've downloaded the source of Soundflower and I am trying to retrieve a list of all applications currently sending data to Soundflower.
I'd like to manipulate each application's sound separately just like JACK and Audio Hijack does.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't something you're going to be able to find out from within the Soundflower kext because applications don't connect directly to audio drivers. The Audio HAL is an audio driver's user client and manages audio input and output between apps and the kernel.

You should look into using a HAL Plug-in. Your plug-in code will get loaded by any application that uses Core Audio and you can do whatever you need to do from there and use some IPC to communicate with your driver and app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ken. I understand that applications don't connect directly to audio drivers, but does the audio driver knows when the application is sending audio to it?

Comment: It's not going to be able to differentiate between applications at the driver level. As I understand it, the HAL mixes audio from all of the applications together and sends the mixed audio to the driver.